# Ошибка в Qt: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Программа падает в Qt после того как я начинаю в ручную записывать библиотеку. Т.е. Я автоматически подкл. в Qt библиотеку (пр кн. мыши по проекту->add Library->External library->...) в pro файле добавляется:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MainClickLib-master/DllClickLib_mingw5.8.0/release/ -lClickLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MainClickLib-master/DllClickLib_mingw5.8.0/debug/ -lClickLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MainClickLib-master/ClickLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MainClickLib-master/ClickLib
```

Все работает
Потом я в ручную пытаюсь записать пути к dll и вылазит при компилировании ошибку: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "../MainClickLib-master/DllClickLib_mingw5.8.0/release/ClickLib.dll"
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += "../MainClickLib-master/DllClickLib_mingw5.8.0/debug/ClickLib.dll"
INCLUDEPATH += "../MainClickLib-master/ClickLib"
DEPENDPATH += "../MainClickLib-master/ClickLib"
```

Почему не получается в ручную подключить пути вроде правильные, что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два варианта: либо у вас проект с подпроектами, из-за чего сбились относительные пути, либо файл библиотеки называется не ClickLib.dll, а, например, libClickLib.dll. Если вы пишете полный путь к файлу библиотеки, нужно указывать точное название файла.

Чем вас стандартный вариант не устраивает?

Comment: Нет файл называеться ClickLib.dll Ну в частности меня не устраивает, тем что это моя библиотека. А кому она понадобиться если даже автор не может свою библиотеку подсоеденить, написав в profile. Честно говоря мне кажется, что я вобще не правильно все организовал в плане git компоновки. Может кому не лень сходите, посмотрите https://github.com/elfenliedmyr/MainClickLib. Буду рад хорошим советам.

Comment: @Madoka Magika, для начала, добавте в .gitignore `*.pro.user` и каталог сборки.

Comment: @Madoka, далее, переменная LIBS имеет формат -L"путь к каталогу" -l"библиотека1" -l"библиотека2", где непосредственное название библиотеки указывается без lib, .so и .dll. Можно указать и полный путь к библиотеке без -L и -l, но в любом случае нужно учитывать, что относительный путь указывается относительно текущего .pro файла, а $$PWD - это корень проекта, из которого вызывается qmake